# How to setState() dynamically in between Parent and Child Component [Logic being run on child & state on the Root App level]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I am fooling around while learning React and I would like to know what would be an elegant solution for the scenario presented below.

Follow this [Link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-exercise-8ttef?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to see the complete code set.

I have a `child` component, that has a `<h1>` `tag`. This tag returns a message that I am displaying dynamically as will be shown below.

**App root container**

I have my `state` on this `container`, and I want to keep it just there.

**State:**

The object of discussion here is the `cockpitAlert` `object`.

```
 state = {
        state = {
    persons: [
      { id: "a", name: "foo1" },
      { id: "b", name: "foo2" },
      { id: "c", name: "foo3" }
    ],
    CockpitAlert: {
      regular: "Some message",
      alert1: "The array is ending",
      alert2: "There is nothing to show"
    }
  };
```

**Below is how I delete the rendered items - still on App.js**

```
personDeleteHandler = index => {
    const person = [...this.state.persons];
    person.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({ persons: person });
  };
```

**Below is where I render my `JSX`**

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Cockpit
          regular={this.state.CockpitAlert.regular}
          alert1={this.state.CockpitAlert.alert1}
          alert2={this.state.CockpitAlert.alert2}
          personsLength={this.state.persons.length}
        />
        <Person click={this.personDeleteHandler} persons={this.state.persons} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**Cockpit child**

Below is the logic. `let message`  dynamically changes the `props` according to the length of the `persons` `array`, that gets shortened upon clicks.

```
import React from "react";

function Cockpit(props) {
  let message = props.regular;
  if (props.personsLength <= 2) {
    message = props.alert1;
  }
  if (props.personsLength === 0) {
    message = props.alert2;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{message}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Cockpit;
```

As you can see this does not look very nice at all.

I don't want to have all of these different `props` being pointed on my logic:

```
regular={this.state.CockpitAlert.regular}
alert1={this.state.CockpitAlert.alert1}
alert2={this.state.CockpitAlert.alert2}
personsLength={this.state.persons.length}
```

I wonder if there is a way that I could pass just one `props`, e.g `props.message` and change it dynamically, probably through `setState()` on the `root` level, where the `state` is set without having to move my logic from `Cockpit` to `App.js`

Comment: So you want to keep the message value in your `App.js` but you want to update it within your `Cockpit` ?

Comment: Yes. I wonder if there is an elegant way of doing this. As you can see I have created 4 props so the variable would point to different props according to the logic being run on my child component. I wonder if I could keep just on ```props``` and somehow set it to different messages, while keeping the logic on the child component and state on the app root container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have discovered how to solve this issue using `React Context API`

here is the updated [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-exercise-8ttef?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

I have first created the file `auth-context.js` in order to pass my state from the `Parent` component to the `child` component.

As the logic is already based on the `Cockpit.js` I will only pass my `state` through `React Context ApI` in this case.

**`auth-context.js` file**

```
import React from 'react'

const authContext = React.createContext({
  persons: [
    { id: "a", name: "foo1" },
    { id: "b", name: "foo2" },
    { id: "c", name: "foo3" }
  ],
  message: "Some message",

});

export default authContext
```

**On my App.js container**

Now I have set the `Provider` in the `App.js` `root` container:

```
//first of all, import the file into the root element which will Provide the //initial state on this API

import AuthContext from "./Context/auth-context";

...

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    persons: [
      { id: "a", name: "foo1" },
      { id: "b", name: "foo2" },
      { id: "c", name: "foo3" }
    ],
    CockpitAlert: {
      message: "Some message"
    }
  };

  personDeleteHandler = index => {
    const person = [...this.state.persons];
    person.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({ persons: person });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        //I am wrapping the whole deal here and set my state so I can manage it at
        // the Cockpit.js file further on
        <AuthContext.Provider
          value={{
            persons: this.state.persons,
            message: this.state.CockpitAlert.message
          }}
        >
         //no more props being passed at Cockpit.js!!!
          <Cockpit />
          <Person
            click={this.personDeleteHandler}
            persons={this.state.persons}
          />
        </AuthContext.Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Now I will pass my `state` into the child component

**`Cockpit.js` file**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
//must import AuthContent here as well.
import AuthContext from "../../Context/auth-context";

function Cockpit(props) {
  //this is the way of setting it up on a functional component
  // now I have access to the state through authContext
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);

  //here I will point my state into different messages
  if (authContext.persons.length <= 2) {
    authContext.message = "running out";
  }
  if (authContext.persons.length === 0) {
    authContext.message = "nothing else to render";
  }
  //as you can see there are no props created
  return <div>{<h1>{authContext.message}</h1>}</div>;
}

export default Cockpit;
```

Now my reflection is:

This is not mutating the original state, at `App.js`. Would this be a good practice in this case?

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a function to the Child component. When the message is defined, it calls the function with the message in parameter. The Parent then receive the message via the function.

```js
// Example class component
class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    message: ""
  }
  
  updateMessage = message => {
    this.setState({
      message: message
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div><b>This is my parent</b></div>
        <Child
          usersLength={0}
          alert1="Alert1"
          alert2="Alert2"
          alert3="Alert3"
          updateMessage={this.updateMessage}
        >
        </Child>
        <Child
          usersLength={1}
          alert1="Alert1"
          alert2="Alert2"
          alert3="Alert3"
          updateMessage={this.updateMessage}
        >
        </Child>
         <Child
          usersLength={2}
          alert1="Alert1"
          alert2="Alert2"
          alert3="Alert3"
          updateMessage={this.updateMessage}
        >
        </Child>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const {usersLength, alert1, alert2, alert3} = props;
    let message = "";
    if(usersLength <= 2) 
      message = alert1;
    if(usersLength <= 1)
      message = alert2;
    if(usersLength === 0)
      message = alert3;
    this.state = {
      message : message
    }
    props.updateMessage(message);
  }

  render() {
    const {message} = this.state;
    return <p>My child message is : {message}</p>
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: If the child is the functional prop, just move the  code from ´constructor´ to `render` and instead of setting the message to the state, just keep it in your variable

Comment: Actually this is not exactly what I am looking for. Once I delete the child list items, the array's length will shorten, then on 1 ```<h2>``` tag i would display different messages according to the array's length.

Comment: I will reformulate the question

Comment: question reformulated!